# How to find all completed PRs across projects in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

How can I find all completed PRs across projects in Azure devops?

I'm looking for them under "My Pull Requests" in devops link, but nothing is showing up?

Comment: This seems more of a documentation question than a programming question. Or... are you asking how to retrieve PR information programmatically? If the latter case, the question itself is still too broad, and you'll want to edit with specifics about where you're stuck, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon No, it is a question regarding the tool of azure devops. And it is a question nobody is able to answer. Good luck you can find it on Azure docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it programmatically with REST API. Simple workflow:

1. Get all projects: [Projects-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
2. Get repositories of each project: [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
3. Get pull requests of each repository: [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#pullrequeststatus)

You could build a hub extension for this requirement: [Add a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-hub?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 14):

Try using this URL: it is natively available in Azure DevOps

```
https://dev.azure.com/your_org/_pulls
```

**Update:** You can also do this now with a new widget ([Pull request multiple repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#pull-request-widget)) built by Microsoft.

Comment: I've been looking for this exact page for ages in DevOps!!

Answer (score 2):

> How to find all completed PRs across projects in Azure devops

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently no out-of-box feature in azure devops to achieve this.

Currently, we can obtain cross-projects Active pull requests through the [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard) extension, but this extension does not provide the function of obtaining completed pull requests. Same goes for "My Pull Requests". We also can't use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests%20by%20project?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) to get completed pull requests across projects. The REST API is only for a single project scope.

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is achievable(just like Active pull requests) ! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/972982/find-all-completed-prs-across-projects-in-azure-de.html) in DC forum. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there.The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Anyone interested in this can also vote for it and track it. Hope this helps.